# Why use "tail -n 1" for finding the nth line of a file in Unix?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I've noticed that people typically use `head -n | tail -n 1` to find the nth line of a file in Shell.

For example, if I was asked to find the 7th line of a file, why not just use `head -7` instead of creating pipelines with `tail`?

Comment: Well, `head -7` is going to give you lines 1-7, not just line 7.

Comment: The "better" way, which some people use, is `sed -n 7p`.

Comment: It's better to use `sed -n -e '7p'` (or `sed -n -e '7p;7q'`) to print the 7th line; it uses fewer processes.  Using `head -n 7` prints 7 lines; if you only want the seventh, then `tail -n 1` prints the last.  The advantage of the `sed` command is that it works more economically when you want line 7654321 instead of line 7.  The variant with `7q` quits after the 7th line; that may generate a SIGPIPE to the process feeding the data to the command sequence.  The variant without `7q` reads all the input, avoiding SIGPIPE signals.  Most commands don't care and stop on SIGPIPE; some are noisy.

Answer (score 5):

```
head -7
```

Or its modern and standard equivalent:

```
head -n 7
```

prints the first 7 lines (or up to 7 if there are fewer) of the input.

piping that to `tail -n 1` gets the last line out of those, so the 7<sup>th</sup> line only or the last line if there are fewer lines.

To get the 7<sup>th</sup> line only (and nothing if there are fewer lines), you'd use:

```
tail -n +7 | head -n 1
```

Which for large values or the line number would also be more efficient as less data goes through the pipe.

You could also do it in one `sed` command:

```
sed '7!d;q'
```

Though that's likely less efficient as `sed` is not as specialised as `head` and `tail`, and `sed` contrary to `head`/`tail` is not required to be able to deal with lines longer than `LINE_MAX` so depending on the implementation may not work on overly long lines.

Note that `sed -n 7p` or `sed '7!d'` as suggested in comments read the whole input even after the 7<sup>th</sup> line has been printed, rather than stop reading there like `head` does. That's less efficient, but in some cases like when applying to the output of a command which we do not want to terminate after its 7<sup>th</sup> line has been output, that might be preferable.